# Passing parameters to jest function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocking, jestjs

I have this function in my child component:

```
<div> {handTotal('dealersHand').total} </div>
```

This has been passed down from above

however when I run jest it says `Cannot read property 'total' of undefined`

when i `console.log(handTotal('dealersHand')` it is logging the right thing and the function works so I know it's doing the correct thing

I've stubbed it out in jest like so:

```
const handTotalStub = jest.fn()
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<Dealer
      dealersHand={dealersHandStub}
      containsAce={containsAceStub}
      handTotal={handTotalStub}
    />);
  })
```

How do I pass the parameter into this function so that jest understands what it is?

can add more code/explanation if doesn't make sense

stubbing:

```
  const handTotalStub = jest.fn().mockReturnValue('dealersHand')
```

test:

```
  it('expects dealers hand to equal', () => {
    expect(handTotalStub('dealersHand').total).toEqual(1);
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your jest spy for `handleTotalStub` does not return anything, so it therefore returns `undefined`.  When your component tries to call `handTotal('dealersHand').total` it is therefore calling `undefined.total`, because `handTotal(...)` is not defined.

Update your spy to return something (anything) by changing

```
handTotalStub = jest.fn();
```

to

```
handTotalStub = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(SOME_VALUE);
```

or

```
handTotalStub = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => SOME_VALUE);
```

(where SOME_VALUE is any value that you can mock out to act as what the component expects to be there)

EDIT --
Ok, so you're misunderstanding what mockReturnValue does.  You don't have to mock the parameters being passed in to that method.  Because your component is already passing in that string.  BUT, the actual `handTotal` method is never going to be called (this is a good thing, because we're not testing how `handTotal` works, we're testing how the component works).

So, whatever `handTotal` would normally return is what you want to put in `mockReturnValue()`.  So if `handTotal` returns an object like `{total: 1}`, then you would say `mockReturnValue({total: 1})`

Comment: ok cheers, but I've done that and it now thinks the whole function is undefined or rather `expected: 1, received: undefined`?

Comment: You're going to need to post the actual test.  I can't see where you're saying `expect(...)...`

Comment: Sorry, also update how you created the stub (what does it return??)

Comment: added that too.

Comment: ah ok nice one, but in terms of actually testing that function, shall I do that in the component above where it is defined?

Comment: Not sure.  That would take knowing what the rest of the component and its parent and all that look like.   That might need to be a different question from this one.